# Nested model doesn't update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-attributes

I have two models: `PointPage` and `PointPageClass`, which `belongs_to :point_page`. When user create `PointPage` rails creates several (now there're 6 of them) `PointPageClasses` in database. I need to edit all of them on `PointPage` `edit` page. So, I'm using nested attributes in controller and `fields_for` in view.

`point_page_form`

```
<%= form_for @point_page, role: 'form' do |f| %>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :name %>
      <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>
    </div>

    ... # some other PointPage fields

    <% @point_page.point_page_classes.each do |class| %>
        <%= f.fields_for :point_page_classes do |builder| %>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-6">
                  <%= builder.text_field :distance_price, class: 'form-control' %>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-6">
                  <%= builder.text_field :show_price, class: 'form-control' %>
              </div>
            </div>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>

    <%= f.submit 'Save', class: 'btn btn-default' %>
<% end %>
```

`point_page_controller`

```
def update
    @point_page = PointPage.find(params[:id])
    if @point_page.update_attributes(point_page_params)
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to new_point_path }
        format.js
      end
    end
end

private

def point_page_params
  params.require(:point_page).permit(:name, :url, :article,
             point_page_classes_attributes: [:distance_price, :show_price])
end
```

So, I've added in `point_page_controller` `PointPageClass` attributes, but when I save the changes, it only saves changes for `PointPage`, but not for `PointPageClass` (`distance_price` and `show_price`).

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Can you show us your `models`?

Comment: Do you have `accepts_nested_attributes_for :point_page_classes` in your model?

Comment: Why you are having this line in the view code <% `@point_page.point_page_classes.each do |class| %>`?

Comment: God bless Iceman :) Thank you, guys. It was such a stupid mistake. I completely forgot about `accepts_nested_attributes_for`. Shame on me :)

Answer (score 1):

One of the problem could be not permitting the `:id` in the `point_page_params`.For the `update` to take place you need to permit the `:id`.

Try changing your `point_page_params` to like this

```
def point_page_params
  params.require(:point_page).permit(:id,:name, :url, :article,point_page_classes_attributes: [:id,:distance_price, :show_price])
end
```